# How to force Visual Studio 2019 to always start with 100% scaling?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like to force Visual Studio to always start with 100% scaling so that the designer doesn't misplace items.

I know of the developer command prompt command: **devenv /noScale**

But how do I do this as a default setting so I wouldn't need to restart VS after opening it?

Comment: [Create a shortcut](https://superuser.com/q/29569/52365) with that?

Answer (score 2):

Add a command like this.

[image]
Add a command like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In fact this solution is the only that worked for me. Just create shortcut (link) for VS2022 and in the textbox for "Target" append at the end /noScale with space before it. Somehow in the latest update of VS2022 with a project for .Net 7 using VB there is not option to restart with 100% scaling. If you do it from developer command prompt what is opened is a blank VS window without your project inside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer, but in Powershell, you could start VS like this in 100% mode:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /noScale
```